# Your Django Development process/steps (Step by Step)

Tags: django, development-process

I want to know step by step process of how folks develop on Django here. I have seen that whenever I try to create a website in Django, I always get confused amongst:

1. DB Schema/models.py
2. UI/Template Structure
3. Login module
4. urls.py
5. views.py

How do you approach this? I may have missed something. You do not need to elaborate everything, just stepwise what you do. If you do two things at the same time (or side-by-side), that would also be helpful to mention.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guideline is that I want to **see something working as soon as possible**. Even if it uses ugly templates, the view is very basic, or even the models are not totally complete.

**This is roughly the order of things**:

1. Settings
2. Models
3. Syncdb
4. Urls
5. Very basic views (mostly using generic views, so very often no need to write any views myself)
6. Create base template (again, nothing fancy)
7. Create a template for each of the views, extending the base template
8. Create tests

And then, I go on a create better models, better views, more fancy templates, or more tests as needed, but not in any specific order - Every time I deal with what I think would give the best value for my time, but the most important thing is **every change is small**. Once you have it running, you can see and test most changes you make in a matter of minutes.